# Org-Mode LaTeX export with section number, name and page in internal links

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I export my Org-Mode notes with internal links to LaTeX and I want it to look like this ''Section 1.1 [Section name], page 99'' (Like in the Org Manual). I use this construction:

```
* Chapter 1
** Section 1.1
 :PROPERTIES:
 :CUSTOM_ID: section-1
 :END:
* Chapter 2
** Section 2.1
I want a reference to Section 1.1 from here (See #section-1)
```

But I only get the number of the section ''1.1'' as a result, not ''Section 1.1 [Section name], page 99''. What options do I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

You should write `[[section-1]]` to get the number only ([source](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html)).

Comment: The OP was specifically asking for three things in the output.  The section number (which is all that your suggestion would give), the section title, AND the page number.  I wish I knew how to get just the page number.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> (Like in the Org Manual)

Just so you do not go down that route, wasting your time: [The Org manual (source link)](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/doc/org.texi) seems to **not** be **written in org-mode**, but in [Texinfo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo) instead. While it might be possible to do what you want, the manual source does not show a way to do this. For example, [the section](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Activation)

> There are compatibility issues between Org mode and some other Elisp packages, please take the time to check the list (see [Conflicts](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Conflicts)).

is [generated by](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/doc/org.texi#n956)

```
There are compatibility issues between Org mode and some other Elisp
packages, please take the time to check the list (@pxref{Conflicts}).
```

Comment: Which tells him how to get a hyper link to the Conflicts page, but does not tell the OP how to get the three things he wants.  The section number, the section name, and the page it appears on.  I'd be happy with knowing how to get a page number for a section or table.

Comment: @EdwinW: as would be several people. If you know an answer, post it. As soon as a real solution exists, this answer by me can be removed. Looking at the org manual seems to be the wrong way to find the solution, though. This answer was just so others do not waste their time trying to find the details in the org manual. If you feel this could be expressed better, feel free to edit.